# Added new column to a table but updateOrCreate method won't update - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just added a new column with `php artisan make:migration` , and after that I called `updateOrCreate` method hoping to filling the new column with values on all the existing records.

But nothing happened. I tracked down and found that the parameter for the new column was passed right to `updateOrCreate` method. But why was it not working? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the column to the `$fillable` array in your model?

Comment: Oh man, you saved me. Thanks for the great comment!

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the question off and give it an answer, as Jeemusu pointed out, you needed to add the new column to your `$fillable` array inside the table model - thus allowing it to be inserted in to your database.